# Xcode UITouch and UIImage user touches images placed where touched

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, user-interface

Xcode Place an Image where the user touches

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
UITouch *touch=[[event allTouches]anyObject];
CGPoint point= [touch locationInView:touch.view];

UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:@"BluePin.png"];
[image drawAtPoint:point];
}
```

Basically touch screen image should appear where touched but nothing appears...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should init a UIImage like this:

   ```
   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BluePin"];
   ```
2. You should use a UIImageView to contain a UIImage, you can not put a UIImage into UIView directly.

**update**

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch=[[event allTouches]anyObject];
    CGPoint point= [touch locationInView:touch.view];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BluePin"];
    CGRect rect=CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:rect];
    [imageView setImage:image];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
}
```

Comment: could you give me an example please?

Comment: thanks you so much!!! also is there a way to have the image fade away over a certain time period? sorry new to Xcode =)

Comment: +1. You ninja'd me after I wrote almost exactly the same code. xD One difference though, is that if you want the pin to go directly under the person's finger (as opposed to having the upper left corner where they touched) you'd have to subtract half of the image width from the x value and half of the image height from the y value when making the frame.

Comment: na this app will be nothing like this i just need to image for an example of what really will happen =P so don't worry and could u give me an example too please?

Answer (score 0):

To add on to the other answer, here's how you could animate it:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    NSLog(@"Touches began!");
    UITouch *touch= [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint point= [touch locationInView:touch.view];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BluePin.png"];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [imageView setFrame: CGRectMake(point.x-(imageView.bounds.size.width/2), point.y-(imageView.bounds.size.width/2), imageView.bounds.size.width, imageView.bounds.size.height)];
    [self addSubview: imageView];
    //self.currentPins += 1;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear  animations:^{
        [imageView setAlpha:0.0];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [imageView removeFromSuperview];
        //self.currentPins -= 1;
    }];

   // for(;self.currentPins > 10; currentPins -= 1){
   //     [[[self subviews] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
   // }
}
```

The commented out code is a little extra I wrote to limit the amount of pins on the screen to ten at a time, assuming you have a @property called *currentPins*. Tested and it works, assuming I didn't mess anything up after copying, pasting and commenting out a few lines.

EDIT: Disregard the commented out code. I actually mixed up two versions (one without animation, one with) so it's broken.

Comment: ok thank you so much!!! and ok will do works great any tips on sites to learn more about Xcode?

Comment: Do you mean learning about Xcode, as in the software IDE (the software), or Objective-C (the programming language) & Cocoa Touch (the framework)? You've referred to everything as Xcode so far. xD Not sure about Xcode, as I learned the interface through tinkering and _Programming iOS 5_. Google up some Xcode 4 tutorials, maybe? As for Objective-C and Cocoa Touch, I recommend reading through Apple's documentation (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html) and getting a good book.

Comment: Yeah obc/cocoa touch thanks any book suggestions i pref e books lol less paper

Comment: I'm reading _Programming iOS 5_ by Matt Neuburg (http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023562.do) right now and it's pretty good. Steps through the features of Xcode, teaches you most of what you need to learn as a solid foundation. It's available is paper, as a PDF and in Mobi and ePub formats for eReaders. It's well written, but beware that it _is_ long (*1000* pages; its wordier than it needs to be sometimes) and doesn't cover Core Data. I'd suggest googling around and seeing what's out there. Also, it seems O'Reilly is having a 50% off sale on all ebooks right now, so that's good timing.

Comment: ok great!!! thank you yeah ive been pretty much just googling things when i need to use them for an app idea

Comment: You're welcome. Things should become easier once you learn the basics, and once you have a solid foundation learning new stuff on top of that becomes a lot easier. Although, as one programmer said (and was cited in _Cocoa in a Nutshell_ according to Pio5) "_You don't remember Cocoa; you look it up!_" Which especially holds true for the more complicated stuff, so don't be surprised if you're still looking stuff up for quite a while. xD

Comment: lol yeah even the simple things can be forgotten if not used constantly thanks